# Setting Job name for Spring batch job

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement to run the same job multiple times in a day. For example: the job name is **myHourlyJob**. This job needs to run every hour and there is a validation that I need to do to check that for a day all 24 jobs ran successfully. My requirement is to add dynamic param in the jobname so I can identify each job based on the name.
For example :

1. the job running on 1st Jan at 9am, the job name should be : myHourlyJob_20220109_9.
2. the job running on 1st Jan at 2pm, the job name should be : myHourlyJob_20220109_14.

In general job name = myHourlyJob_YYYYMMDD_jobRunHour

It is possible to define the job name in Spring batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the job name should not be changed, it is the same the job so it should have the same name. What you are describing is exactly the concept of job instance in Spring Batch, one instance for each hour in your case. It is the same job, it does the same thing over and over again, why should it have 24 names a day?

I suggest you keep a single name for your job, and launch a different instance every hour. In your case, the run time (the hour of the day) should be passed as an identifying job parameter and you will have 24 job instances for the same job per day. Please refer to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/domain.html#job) for more details about these concepts.